# Pandas: Getting 0s and the NaNs when Normalizing Data

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having some trouble normalizing my data in Pandas.  I've created a model and am trying to use it to predict.

First, I have this:

```
_text_img_count  _text_vid_count  _text_link_count  _text_par_count  ...
0                2                0                 6
```

Then I normalize as follows:

```
    x = numeric_df.values #returns a numpy array
    min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
    x_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(x)
    numeric_df_normalized = pd.DataFrame(x_scaled)
```

Now, `numeric_df_normalized` looks like this:

```
 0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9  ...    13   14   15   16  \
0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0 ...   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   

    17   18   19   20   21   22  
0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

So I've lost my column names and my values are all 0.

Finally, I try to add back the old column names from the original `numeric_df` as follows:

```
numeric_df_normalized = pd.DataFrame(numeric_df_normalized, columns=numeric_df.columns)
```

I get back:

```
_text_img_count  _text_vid_count  _text_link_count ...
            NaN              NaN               NaN
```

So a few questions:

1) Why does normalization cause me to lose my column names and set them to 0?

2) Why does adding back the column names from `numeric_df` cause my 0s to be converted to NaNs?

Thanks!

Comment: what is the minimum and the maximum value of x (x.max() and x.min())?

Comment: 1. Check min and max values. 2. You are creating dataframe from dataframe... it is better to use this: numeric_df_normalized = pd.DataFrame(x_scaled, columns=numeric_df.columns)

Answer (score 3):

> 1) Why does normalization cause me to lose my column names and set them to 0?

[MinMaxScaler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html):

```
X_std = (X - X.min(axis=0)) / (X.max(axis=0) - X.min(axis=0))
X_scaled = X_std * (max - min) + min
```

So when data min == data max, the scaled result is 0.

> 2) Why does adding back the column names from numeric_df cause my 0s to be converted to NaNs?

Note that `numeric_df_normalized` is a dataframe already, so `pd.DataFrame(numeric_df_normalized, columns=numeric_df.columns)` would try to match the current dataframe with new columns. Because there is no matching column name, the resulted data is NaN.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to transform the result to a dataframe with the same structure, you can do:

```
numeric_df_normalized.columns=numeric_df.columns
numeric_df_normalized.index=numeric_df.index
```

(the second line is in case you had an index as well) instead of

```
numeric_df_normalized = pd.DataFrame(numeric_df_normalized, columns=numeric_df.columns)
```

Regarding the 0's, this may happen if the values in the first row are the smallest possible values for each one of the features. Then when they are scaled they will be transformed to 0.

For example, consider the following normalization:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing

df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2],'b':[3,4]})

min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
x_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(df.values)
```

`x_scaled` is

```
array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.]])
```

So the upper left 1 became 0 (since 1<2) and the upper right 3 became 0 (since 3<4).